# Avoid multiple counting of overlapped times

Tags: sql-server, datetime, overlap, counting

I have calculated the overlap times between start_time and end_time for groups of IDs for multiple user logins sessions. ID is unique to a user. A user can have multiple sessions from different browsers, devices, etc.

Here's the dataset I have

```
row       id       start_time        end_time       overlap_in_seconds
1         1        08:41:27          08:47:26       359 
2         1        08:39:31          08:40:42       71
3         1        08:41:37          08:47:26       349
```

If you notice for rows 1 and 3 the time overlap time between 08:41:37 and 08:47:26 has been counted twice.

There are 2 options how I would like to show the result:

Option 1:

```
row        id       start_time        end_time       overlap_in_seconds
 1         1        08:41:27          08:47:26       10 (the extra overlap time from 08:41:27 to 08:41:37)
 2         1        08:39:31          08:40:42       71
 3         1        08:41:37          08:47:26       349
```

Option 2:

I use this table as a temp table and in the outer query when I do a sum on Overlap_in_seconds, I get the total overlap time as 430 seconds (10+71+349), not 779(349+359+71).

```
meeting_id.    correct_overlap
1              430
```

Below is my outer query.

```
select temp.id as meeting_id, sum(temp.Overlap_in_seconds) as correct_overlap
from temp
group by temp.id
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the quickest way to do it, but what i would is to convert every date to a 86400 bit array, every position correspond to each second in the day, next just simply join all the arrays and it will be the seconds for each group.